# How to add subtitles to video with CATextLayer

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to add subtitles to a video that i have captured with my app but i can't figure how to do it. So far i can only add a single string to the whole video using this code:

```
CATextLayer *aLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
aLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
aLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
aLayer.string = @"Text goes here";
aLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:urlVideo options:nil];

self.cmp = [AVMutableComposition composition];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *trackA = [self.cmp addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVAssetTrack *sourceVideoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
[trackA insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset duration]) ofTrack:sourceVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil] ;

self.animComp = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
self.animComp.renderSize = CGSizeMake(640, 480);
self.animComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,30);

CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 480);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 480);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:aLayer];

self.animComp.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset duration]);
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:trackA];

[layerInstruction setOpacity:1.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction] ;
self.animComp.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:instruction];
[self exportMovie:self];
```

To be more specific, i would like to add some strings to certain frames of the movie.

Comment: Any success over this?

Answer (score 1):

That won't be an exact answer but you can either use CAMediaTimingFunction or you can use the part in your code where you set the timer of the subtitle with kCMTimeZero. You can put timer for the string you added by changing kCMTimer values for each string you like to add in order to add subtitles.